# How to disable space bar on form, keypress - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I have tried searching for this all over but can't seem to find any solutions.

What i want to do is to disable the Space bar from being a usable key because it meddles with the functioning of my game.

Also to clarify this needs to be done through the keypreview on the form's screen and not a textbox.

I want to disable the use of the spacebar from being a detectable keypress. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Use KeyHook https://gist.github.com/Stasonix/3181083

Comment: Sorry but I am new to VB and that stuff is extremely advanced, would you be able to explicitly tell me what i would need to type and where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the answer to this question; to do it you need to add a keydown event handler to the control you wish to disable the key for. Then type the code:

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.space Then
    e.SuppressKeyPress = True
End If
```

This would work for other keys such as enter and other keys also. Just change the `"keys."` to the key you wish to disable/suppress.

Comment: If you set the Form.KeyPreview property to True then you can write that code in the Form's KeyDown event handler instead of copy/pasting it to kingdom come.

Comment: Yes, that is also true for when you want it to work across the entire form. But if you want it to work in a specific textbox then that's a different story. GOOD TIP!!

Answer (score 0):

Use Key Hooking mechanism.

Example In VB [Here](http://www.developer.com/net/net/article.php/11087_2193301_3/Managing-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hooks-in-VB-NET.htm) And [Here](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_disable_keys.html)

Example In C# [Here](https://gist.github.com/Stasonix/3181083) and [Low-level Windows API hooks from C# to stop unwanted keystrokes](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14485/Low-level-Windows-API-hooks-from-C-to-stop-unwante)

If you are not familiar with C# you can use [code converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) to to get source code form VB to understand the code. but some time not 100% convert.

**Full Code**

**To use this code : Insert CheckBox and TextBox in to Win Form**

```
Public Class Form1
    Declare Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" (ByVal idHook As Integer, ByVal lpfn As LowLevelKeyboardProcDelegate, ByVal hMod As IntPtr, ByVal dwThreadId As Integer) As IntPtr
    Declare Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" Alias "UnhookWindowsHookEx" (ByVal hHook As IntPtr) As Boolean
    Declare Function CallNextHookEx Lib "user32" Alias "CallNextHookEx" (ByVal hHook As IntPtr, ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByRef lParam As KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT) As Integer
    Delegate Function LowLevelKeyboardProcDelegate(ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByRef lParam As KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT) As Integer

    Const WH_KEYBOARD_LL As Integer = 13

    Structure KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
        Dim vkCode As Integer
        Dim scanCode As Integer
        Dim flags As Integer
        Dim time As Integer
        Dim dwExtraInfo As Integer
    End Structure

    Dim intLLKey As IntPtr
    Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
        If CheckBox1.Checked Then
            intLLKey = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, AddressOf LowLevelKeyboardProc, IntPtr.Zero, 0)
        Else
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(intLLKey)
        End If

    End Sub
    Private Function LowLevelKeyboardProc(ByVal nCode As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByRef lParam As KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT) As Integer
        Dim blnEat As Boolean = False

        Select Case wParam
            Case 256, 257, 260, 261
                'Alt+Tab, Alt+Esc, Ctrl+Esc, Windows Key    
                blnEat = ((lParam.vkCode = 9) AndAlso (lParam.flags = 32)) Or _
                ((lParam.vkCode = 27) AndAlso (lParam.flags = 32)) Or _
                ((lParam.vkCode = 27) AndAlso (lParam.flags = 0)) Or _
                ((lParam.vkCode = 91) AndAlso (lParam.flags = 1)) Or _
                ((lParam.vkCode = 92) AndAlso (lParam.flags = 1)) Or _
                ((lParam.vkCode = 32) AndAlso (lParam.flags = 0)) 'this is the space key code 32

        End Select

        If blnEat = True Then
            Return 1
        Else
            Return CallNextHookEx(IntPtr.Zero, nCode, wParam, lParam)
        End If
    End Function

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(intLLKey)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Really not necessary, seems like a bit of overkill for such a simple function, by the way you could have sent link to website instead of copy pasta, at least source it

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
    Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef m As Message, key As Keys) As Boolean
    Select Case keyData
            Case (key.Space)
                 Return True
    Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(m , key)
```